# Map existing database to existing model

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

If I have a database (SQL Server 2008) with about 100 tables, 50 stored procedures e.t.c. – it has really good proven design. And let’s say I already have a very convenient model which we use in several applications – it is set of classes that reflect database structure. I.e. I have database and don’t want to create the model and I have a model and don’t want to create the database, but I still keen in using EF 5.0. Here is my question. Is there any way to map existing database to existing model without recreating one of them. The only option, I can think of is using CodeFirst approach and creating all the DbSets via FluentApi and setting database initializer to null at the same time. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your approach is correct. However you should be sure that your database model is build according to EF default [naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh161541%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) (e.g Column names, Relations). 
If it's not you should override mapping per each 'not conventioned' model entity in you DbContext class using FluentAPI or attributes in model. 
I have not tried EF 5 but it should have support of [pluggable conventions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/10/ef-feature-ctp5-pluggable-conventions.aspx). So you may try
to use them if you convention is not recognized by EF by default. 
Also you may want to check whether your associated properties are virtual in model to enable lazy loading.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two strategies:

1. Generate the entities from the database and use composition or intermediate classes to have your model communicate to the entities.
2. [Use your model as POCO classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd468057%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You will have to adapt your model then to have it comply with the prerequisites for this.

As you are using a lot of stored procedures, the database first approach is the best IMHO. Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx) about how to map those.